# Cannot save array's first value to the object value problem

Tags: angular, typescript

I have option selection box in HTML. I already managed how to send the selected items (in my example id of the course) to the array, from that box. Is saves to `courseDataSend` like `['1']` or `['1','2']`. I can `console.log()` it.

But now I need to create an object **`sendCourse`** with property **`id_course`** and that `id_course` should be taken from from **`courseDataSend`** array, so I tried to pass it through like:

```
reg()
  {
    for(let i=0; i<this.courseDataToSend.length; i++)
    {
      console.log(this.courseDataToSend[i])   // It shows '1' or '1' and then '2' when options selected
      this.sendCourse.id_course=this.courseDataToSend[i]
    }
  }
```

`reg()` happens after button click submit. But then this error appears in console:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'id_course' of undefined

The For loop is there because I want to create the object once, send it to the server, and then if there is another option selected from the box - the object is replaced by the new data and then again sent to the backend server.

I don't know what do do.

register.component.ts

```
  coursesData : any = {}
  courseDataToSend : Array<string> = []
  sendCourse : {
    'id_user': any,
    'id_course': any,
  }

  constructor(
    private _auth: AuthService,
    private _courseService: CourseService,
    private _router: Router,
    private _flashMessage: FlashMessagesService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this._courseService.getCourses()
      .subscribe(
        res => 
        {
          this.coursesData= res['courses'];
          console.log(this.coursesData)
        }
      )
  }

  reg()
  {
    for(let i=0; i<this.courseDataToSend.length; i++)
    {
      console.log(this.courseDataToSend[i])   // It shows '1' or '1' and then '2' when options selected
      this.sendCourse.id_course=this.courseDataToSend[i]
    }
  }
```

register.component.html:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="registerCourses">Select your courses (additional):</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="courseDataToSend" name="courses" multiple class="form-control"
            id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
            <option *ngFor="let course of coursesData" [value]="course.id">{{course.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <small id="interestsHelp" class="form-text text-muted">To select more: hold control button and
            click</small>
    </div>

        <div class="text-right">
            <button (click)="reg()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                style="margin: 15px;">Register</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). JSON is a text format, like CSV or XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your sendCourse variable declaration as follows

```
sendCourse : any = {
    'id_user': '',
    'id_course': ''
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to trying to set an object value before the variable is defined. You need to either set the entire object:

```
for(let i=0; i<this.courseDataToSend.length; i++)
{
  console.log(this.courseDataToSend[i])   // It shows '1' or '1' and then '2' when options selected
  this.sendCourse = { id_course: this.courseDataToSend[i], id_user: undefined }
}
```

or at minimum initialize your `sendCourse` object:

```
  sendCourse : {
    'id_user': any,
    'id_course': any,
  } = { id_user: undefined, id_course: undefined }
```

Working stackblitz example which shows how undefined and null propagate and can be handled for each case:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mkesxe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts